# Non sono sicuro/a + "che" o "se"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conjunctions

Quando si deve usare "*che*" e quando "*se*" dopo la locuzione "*non sono sicuro/a*"?

Per contestualizzare, si discuta quale sia la forma corretta fra le seguenti 1) e 2):

> 1) Non sono sicura *che* questa parola sia ben scritta.
>
> 2) Non sono sicura *se* questa parola sia ben scritta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In questo specifico caso userei la prima, mi sembra una **proposizione subordinata oggettiva**. Il secondo caso mi sembra invece un'**interrogativa indiretta** (qui il messaggio sarebbe *«non sono sicura ma mi domando se sia così»*).

Entrambe comunque andrebbero bene, seppur con significati forse non del tutto equivalenti.

Diverso sarebbe stato il caso in cui avessi usato il verbo *sapere*: avresti allora dovuto dire

> *«non so se questa parola sia ben scritta»* (**interrogativa indiretta**);

mentre invece sarebbe stato un errore dire

> *«non so che questa parola sia ben scritta»*.

Avresti potuto dire però

> *«che questa parola sia ben scritta o meno, non lo so»* (**interrogativa indiretta disgiuntiva**).

Significativamente, al positivo e con l'indicativo andrebbe bene:

> *«so che questa parola è ben scritta»* (**oggettiva**).

Invece al negativo e al tempo passato, puoi dire

> *«non sapevo che questa parola fosse ben scritta (ma adesso lo so)»* (**oggettiva**).

Come vedi, usando il verbo *sapere*, diventano più chiare le diverse sfumature.

Comment: Non credo che, nella domanda, il punto interrogativo posto alla fine di 'non sono sicura se questa parola sia ben scritta' sia riferito o connesso a questa frase, ma, piuttosto, credo sia riferto alla domanda stessa. Ora suggerisco una correzione per evitare questo pasticcio.

Comment: OK, però le interrogative indirette non vogliono il punto interrogativo, quindi non credo che ci possano essere equivoci.