# Differenza tra "va bene che" e "va bene se"

Tags: grammar, difference, conjunctions

Sono due espressioni che possono sostituirsi a vicenda in ogni contesto (frasi interrogative e affermative)  oppure si usa "se" nelle frasi interrogative e "che" in quelle affermative?

Tipo:

"Va bene se resto qui?"

"Sì, va bene che resti qui."

Comment: Domanda correlata: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2363/non-sono-sicuro-a-che-o-se.

Comment: Puoi usare "va bene se" anche nelle frasi affermative.

Comment: @OrlandoB.Manta: Questo mi sembra più un commento che una risposta. Potresti per favore argomentare meglio?